# how to fix this exception in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

I am using jxa-1.0 to create Instant Messaging application in blackberry while running the application i m getting exception like "java.io.IOException: Stream closed".Could you please tell me how to fix this?? or if u have prior experience with Jxa-1.0 pls share your ideas about how to use this one.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid this error on simulators, you should read the InputStream one byte at a time, try this code (consider NOT using this method when working with a real device, since performance will be affected):

```
    InputStream is = httpConnection.openInputStream();
int data = -1;
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
data = is.read();
bos.write(data);
while (data >= 0) {
 try {
  data = is.read();
 } catch (Exception e) {
  // Replace exception with "-1". This is to handle anomalous End-of-Stream in OS 5.
  data = -1;
 }
 bos.write(data);
}
byte[] byteArray = bos.toByteArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing this error message in a simulator, don't be surprised.  I see I/O errors like this quite often in simulators, especially over Direct TCP or Wi-Fi connections.  Some of the newer 5.0 simulators seem to be more problematic than older ones.

If you haven't yet, try it on a real device and it will probably be better.

Comment: Do you have prior experience in Instant Message client programming using Jabber protocol for blackberry?? Please share your ideas about how to develop jabber client application.I could not have clear idea about how to use jxa1.0.

Comment: No, I work more on streaming audio.  I haven't done IM or used that library - just sharing my experience with the simulator that might be affecting you (I assume you're using HTTP).